# How to add dynamically a collapse in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used bootstrap collapse, now I want to add a collapse section dynamically by clicking add new banner in javascript and this is the code.

```
<button type="button" name="submit"  style="margin-left:250px;" class="btn 
btn-primary" onclick="bannerfunction();">Add Banner</button>   
  <div class="card" style="display:none;" id="welcomeDiv">
 <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
 controls="collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </button>
  </h5>
 </div>
 <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data- 
 parent="#accordionExample">
  <div class="card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus 
  terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat 
 skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 
 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee 
 nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer 
labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur 
butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim 
 aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus 
 labore sustainable VHS.
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  function bannerfunction() {

  }
  </script>
```

check the image link here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18C0D.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add a new div and/or add a new class?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a new div of collapse like above forth banner, when I click add new banner it must create a new banner like the fifth banner ...